# Accessing html form elements with runat=server

Tags: asp.net

I have a select box in an asp.net form like so:

```
<form action="Process.aspx" method="post">
  <select  name="referer" id="refererSelect" runat=server>
    <option value="">Please select one ...</option>
    <option value="customer">Return Customer</option>
    <option value="referral">Client Referral</option>
    <option value="trade">Trade Show</option>
    <option value="search">Search Engine</option>
    <option value="ad">Advertisement</option>
</select>
```

This way I can set a session variable with the same name in Process.aspx:

```
private static string[] keys = {"name", "email", "company", "budget", "referer", "services", "comment"};

protected void saveToSesh()
{
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection form = Request.Form;
    foreach (string key in keys)
    {
        Session.Add(key, form[key]);
    }
}
```

, and then set the value of the select box when the user returns later like so:

```
string referer = (string) Session["referer"];
foreach (ListItem i in refererSelect.Items)
    if (referer == i.Value)
        i.Selected = true;
```

The problem is when the form is sent to the server, the form key gets changed to "ctl00$content$refererSelect". Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: `Session[]` wouldn't pull it from the request, where are you getting the form variable?

Comment: I'm trying to do this using very basic html. I'm sending to another page that'll do the processing, process.aspx whose code will set the session variable based on the Request.Form key.

Comment: This is a very confusing question dude, but I can see that you're trying. :) I would put a breakpoint on your session.add line and go through in debug mode... I think the value must already be wrong at the point where you call form[key].

Comment: Which is to say, if the form[key] is wrong, your session variable will be wrong, and then you will have problems at the final point. I assume there is a reason why you have to use session here, but if not I would avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your issue probably lives wherever the session variable 'referer' is  assigned.

I think you're assigning MyControl.UniqueID when you actually need MyControl.ID (which does not have all the naming container-related goo).

[Read this](http://blogs.telerik.com/atanaskorchev/posts/08-06-06/the_difference_between_id_clientid_and_uniqueid.aspx) to learn more about how that all works.